# Need to run a sh everyday at 9 am and keep running every 10 secs

Tags: linux, bash, cron, raspberry-pi, sleep

Im programming a raspberry camera

So, I need to execute a sh script everyday at 9 AM but then, the script has to run every 10 seconds.

Like it starts doing photos at 6 am and do them every 10 seconds until i automaticlly reboot the system so it stops the command.

```
00 09 * * 1 watch -n 10 sh /home/pi/timelapse/process1.sh
00 09 * * 2 watch -n 10 sh /home/pi/timelapse/process1.sh
00 09 * * 3 watch -n 10 sh /home/pi/timelapse/process1.sh
00 09 * * 4 watch -n 10 sh /home/pi/timelapse/process1.sh
00 09 * * 5 watch -n 10 sh /home/pi/timelapse/process1.sh

00 17 * * 1 sudo reboot
00 17 * * 2 sudo reboot
00 17 * * 3 sudo reboot
00 17 * * 4 sudo reboot
00 17 * * 5 sudo reboot

30 17 * * 1 sh /home/pi/timelapse/newimage/video.sh
30 17 * * 2 sh /home/pi/timelapse/newimage/video.sh
30 17 * * 3 sh /home/pi/timelapse/newimage/video.sh
30 17 * * 4 sh /home/pi/timelapse/newimage/video.sh
30 17 * * 5 sh /home/pi/timelapse/newimage/video.sh
```

reboot crontab have to stop first command at 5 PM so i dont need to program it to stop. Then it does a video with all the photos in the command.

I tried with crontab, watch and sleep but crontab just dont run them even in an sh script.

it is supose to create images in a folder and it doesnt. I let the code right here. when i execute it manually, it works.

```
raspistill -w 1920 -h 1080 -o /home/pi/timelapse/images/imageBTW.jpg DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S") for file in "/home/pi/timelapse/images/imageBTW.jpg" ; do convert "$file" \ -pointsize 72 -fill white -annotate +100+100 \ %[exif:DateTimeOriginal] /home/pi/timelapse/newimage/$DATE.jpg done rm /home/pi/timelapse/images/imageBTW.jpg
```

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd write a shell script that has a loop that runs with a delay of 10 seconds in it. Then just launch that at 9:00 am. I'd use cron just to launch it at the right time. After that, the repeated calls would  happen inside the script itself.

Comment: Can the script run for more than 10 seconds? And if yes what should be done then?

Comment: It has to creates an image called ImageBTW, adds timestamp to it and renames it with the date, then sends it to newimage folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this: [`man 5 crontab`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/)

There you will find the information, that `cron` works only with minute precision.

But you can write the following into your `crontab`:

```
0 9 * * 1-5 watch -n 10 sh -c 'while /home/pi/timelapse/process1.sh; do sleep 10; done'
```

BTW whom do you want to spy out?

Comment: hahahaha, thanks a lot, not spying anyone just timelapsing project.

Comment: It still dont work, it is supose to create images in a folder and it doesnt. I let the code right here. when i execute it manually, it works. I edited the question.